# Initialize a function with fields in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In javascript, we can define hybrid things between a function and an object, for example:

```js
function compute(params) {
  return Buffer.from(/* ... */)
}
compute.hex = function(params) {
  return this(params).toString('hex')
}
```

In typescript, we can type such an object with:

```
interface BinHex {
  (params: Params): Buffer
  hex(params: Params): string
}
```

The question is how can I initialize such an object in a clean/idomatic way ?

I can do this:

```
let compute: BinHex =
  function(params: Params): Buffer {/*...*/} as BinHex // ugly cast

compute.hex = function(params) { return this(params).toString('hex') }
```

Or that:

```
const compute: BinHex = Object.assign(
  function(params: Params): Buffer { /*...*/ },
  {
    hex(this: BinHex /* ugly cast */, params) {
      return this(params).toString('hex')
    }
  }
) // Object.assign returns any so it's not type safe
```

I tried a few other variations, but can't find a way to do this without casts. Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe try making the hex function optional in the interface? Maybe you could use the `Partial` type to do so

Comment: Good idea, but it won't check if I set hex or not. This is a simplified case, in reality I have a few fields, not just one.